# Class Method that Constructs a New Instance

Tags: coffeescript

I'd like to emulate [ActiveRecord scopes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope) on a CoffeeScript class.

What's tripping me up is the context when defining the `@scope` function. The `@scope` function itself should execute in the context of the underlying class, but the function it is passed should operate in the context of that instance.

Here is what I have, but the `popped` function ends up running in the context of Window instead of the instance that called it.

```
class Collection
  models: []

  @scope: (name, funct) ->
    @.prototype[name] = ->
      new @constructor(funct())

  constructor: (models) ->
    @models = models

class Bubbles extends Collection
  @scope 'popped', ->
    @models.slice(1, @models.length)

  first: ->
    @models[0]


console.log(new Bubbles([1,2,3,4]).popped()) # should return an instance of Bubbles with models == [2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `funct` as a simple function:

```
new @constructor(funct())
```

so `@` inside `funct` is going to be `window`. You can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to specify what `@` should be (i.e. to call the function as a method):

```
@scope: (name, funct) ->
  @::[name] = ->
    new @constructor(funct.apply(@))
```

Note that I've also switched to `::` as that's more idiomatic CoffeeScript that `prototype`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9Pmcr/